# Manage a MySql Database using Drupal

Tags: database

I want to have something similar to phpmyadmin(not as robust as it though)
Is there any way that I can display the contents in my database in a table and allow download of the content(there is a blob field in the table which contains a file).
Also the users must be able to add content into the database : as in just upload a new file to the database.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

For me also need a phpmyadmin for drupal.So i copied a latest phpmyadmin to my modules (sites/all/modules/) folder of drupal.Then i just request in my browser like "http://localhost/proj1/sites/all/modules/mysql/index.php".The phpmyadmin page home page run successfully and asked me a username and password.I gave them, it logged in and showing me all the tables inside the db.Try this way.Also carefull with normal user db operation.I don't know how to configure permission of phpmyadmin with drupal users.

Comment: Thanks.It is good to know that.But I  wanted to know if there is any way this can be done with some drupal modules.
I know showing the content in the database is easy.What about adding files?Is there any module that does it or do we have to use php

Comment: Can you try node import module, you can download it from http://drupal.org/project/node_import

Comment: So I am thinking of doing this  Create a custom content type which has the details of my database : id,name,status,published,content(blob)  And I want to import the records into drupal.  Then my original mysql table and drupal must be in sync.i.e when the user updates/adds content,it must be changed in mysql as well.  Is this feasible?

Comment: yes it's fine!!